Microcontroller adjusting opamp in audio circuit
I'd like to use a microcontroller (ATmega probably) to adjust an audio circuit. There is analog output with adjustable output voltage. I came up with a idea limit feedback signal with a transistor like in the following picture. Could that work? Transistor probably needs to be FET because BJT has polarity. I'd have C945 BJTs, but they are probably no-go with this idea.

And thank you for helping electric newbie whit his (stupid?) ideas.

Are you trying to build a VCA?

Well, kind of yes. I've made years ago a compressor and disortion fx for guitar. Both of them used opamps in the circuit and I was thinking that it would be fun to build similar but controlled by a microcontroller.

Certainly possible. If low volume, I'd recommend paying yourself away from all issues and purchase a THAT 2181 VCA IC.

Are you aware that there are digital potentiometers that can be controlled by microcontrollers?  They work much like your FET, but are arguably simpler to use.

Some MCUs have a built-in DAC so it could be used for generating the analog control signal.
ATMegas are old and simple and don't have DACs.
In such a case you need to build a DAC circuit. You can buy a DAC chip and send data to it. You can build a R2R ladder DAC. Or you can output a high speed PWM signal and lowpass filter it to DC with small enough ripple.
In case you want to get rid of the FET too, digital potentiometers with MCU interface do exist so you can adjust the resistance.
However, what you really might want instead is a dedicated audio volume control chip with some MCU interface.

Oh yes, you're right. ATMega has ADC but not DAC. That adds complexity a bit. And this whole project (or not even that, rather just an idea) is for learning, So I wanted to avoid specific purpose IC:s such as volume control chip or even digital potentiometer.

Your schematic is that of a comparator with hysteresis, not a linear amplifier.  A linear amplifier uses negative feedback, not positive feedback as shown.
If you search for 'voltage controlled amplifier schematic' (without the quote marks) and go to Images, you will get hundreds of examples.  It might be overwhelming at first, but as you go through them you will see that there are a small number of approaches that are similar.
Many of these are either a JFET as part is an attenuator in front of a fixed-gain amplifier, or the JFET as the shunt element (from the inverting input to GND) of a standard non-inverting amplifier.  This latter one varies the gain of the amplifier circuit rather than the amplitude of the amplifier input.

With a JFET, its resistance will not only depend on the gate voltage, but also on the output voltage, which will obviously lead to terribly lots of distortion.
A much better representation of a analog controllable resistance can be had by using an optorelay instead of the JFET. A typical MCU output of 0..3.3 V is more than enough to give you access to the entire resistance range from >1 Gohm down to ~10 Ohm or less for some parts.
For reference, I am talking about ready-to-use integrated components, such as TLP175 or CPC1017 and nothing you have to build yourself.

For a one-off solution, "optorelay" suggested by @tobalt is a good idea. They are also called "Vactrols". The simplest way to achieve this is to put a LED and a photoresistor together, encase them in some kind of black putty, and then PWM control the LED from the microcontroller.

This might be more difficult than an integrated photorelay, but will probably give better linearity (as in: less dependence on signal level). Are there integrated solutions?

@tobalt Vactrols were the integrated solution, but they are quite obsolete now when controlling analog audio with them hasn't been a thing for decades. One part of the problem is RoHS as these devices simply were a LED and CdS LDR in one plastic package, and cadmium based LDRs are also obsolete.
